# Convert image uploaded by using HttpPostedBasefile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert image to byte array when i upload image using httppostedbasefile
my code is here

> Imageconverterclass

```
    public static class UtilImageConverter
{
    public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        var imgCon = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(imageIn, typeof(byte[]));
    }

}
```

> My method

```
 foreach (var file in postModels.FileName)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = "";
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        if (fileName != null)
                        {
                            Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName);
                            byte[] imagearray = UtilImageConverter.ImageToByteArray(img);
                        }
                    }
```

> I receive following error

[image]

Comment: You mean the [PasswordFor Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.passwordfor(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'instead of showing values'? Do you want to add a password text box?

Comment: for example if there is username "abc" i want to show " *** " instead of abc ...just to hide a real characters like dots or * for password...

Comment: Use `@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.YourProperty)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.YourProperty)
```

or

```
<input type="password" value = "@Model.YourProperty" />
```

Be aware that someone can still see the value by inspecting the HTML... If you don't want them to see it, don't pass the value to the View.

If you are not rendering it in an input control, just set the value of your property to *** (you could do something like take the original value's length + x to mask that value further)